# How to determine if a volume supports Trash?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am writing an app that will be deleting files.  If the volume supports the Trash folder, I want to move the files there, otherwise just remove them.

It may just be my search mojo failing me, but I cannot find how to do this.

The intent here is to do something like (pseudocode):

```
if (itemURL on volume that supports Trash)
    use trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:
else
    use removeItemAtURL:error:
```

I am aware of **recycleURLs:completionHandler:** but, for SMB volumes for example, it puts up a dialog about how the file(s) will be immediately deleted.  And I would like to deal the the files individually so that I can update a display.  I suppose I could use **recycleURLs:completionHandler:** if File System Events work on SMB volumes but I am not sure they do.

Anyhoo..Is there some API I am missing or some recommended technique that I just cant seem to find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice person from the Apple Dev Forums hunted up the answer:

[From the 10.8 Foundation release notes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html)

> NSFileManager Trash APIs In Mac OS 10.8, NSFileManager has new methods
>   to manage the Trash. The  -[NSFileManager
>   trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:] will attempt to  move the item
>   at the given URL to the trash, returning the resulting URL  by
>   reference. As part of this operation, the system may rename the file 
>   to avoid name conflicts; if so, the resultingItemURL will reflect this
>   new name.
>
> [snip]
>
> Some volumes may not support a Trash folder, so these methods will 
>   report failure by returning NO or nil and an NSError with 
>   NSFeatureUnsupportedError. NSFeatureUnsupportedError is a new error
>   code  in the NSCocoaErrorDomain that indicates a failure to perform
>   the  requested operation because the feature is not supported, either
>   because  the file system lacks the feature, or required libraries are
>   missing,  or other similar reasons.

Not sure why that doc never came up on search.

Comment: If you need code that will run before 10.8, you can use the deprecated function `FSPathMoveObjectToTrashSync`.

Comment: 10.8 is fine for my purpose, but that is a good point for other folks.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only works if you are able to try to trash a file. If you want to know if a volume supports the trash but don't have any files to test, then you should check the result of

```
FileManager.default.url(for: .trashDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: url, create: false)
```

where `url` is the url of the volume or a file on that volume.