# How to know whether a file can be moved to the trash in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, volume, recycle-bin

Currently I'm able to trash selected user files. The question is how to know whether the volume of that file supports trashing. For example, external USB sticks just have a local trash folder, while trashing a file on a remote Mac is not allowed (even from the Finder), it can only be deleted. I didn't find any appropriate constant among the `NSURLVolume[...]` ones to use with `[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error]`.

Comment: which way you  trashing files now?

Comment: Sorry, what? It doesn't matter how files are trashed, they simply can't.

Comment: Well, if you consider that local files can be moved and other files do not, then you just need to analyze the file path; in case the file path starts with '/Volumes/', then it isn't in the system disk.

Comment: @vitormm Local partitions alongside Macintosh HD which support trashing also reside in the Volumes folder.

Comment: Uhh, true. Well, another option would be to identify the names of the disk0 (Mac hard disk) partitions and, in case the path is inside /Volumes/, only accept the ones that belong to these guys. I already have a code that does that, in case that solves your problem.

Comment: I've removed my answer since it doesn't help answering the question and makes it easier to find in case someone is looking for unanswered questions.

Comment: This can be accomplished by using the `NSFileManager` and `trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479522/how-to-determine-if-a-volume-supports-trash

Comment: With this method you trash the file directly, but my question is about how to know if a file can be trashed, for example when showing a menu item that would read "Trash file" if trashing is supported or "Delete file" otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking the result of the following method:

```
FileManager.default.url(for: .trashDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: url, create: false)
```

where `url` is the url of the volume or a file on that volume.